# Variable is out of scope?

Tags: java

This is a homework assignment from my teacher. I'm stuck on this part though. It says it's out of scope but I return the variable.

```
public static String monthConvert(int month) {
    String monthborn;

    if (month == 12) {
        monthborn = "December";
    } else if (month == 11) {
        monthborn = "November";
    } else if (month == 10) {
        monthborn = "October";
    } else if (month == 9) {
        monthborn = "September";
    } else if (month == 8) {
        monthborn = "August";
    } else if (month == 7) {
        monthborn = "July";
    } else if (month == 6) {
        monthborn = "June";
    } else if (month == 5) {
        monthborn = "May";
    } else if (month == 4) {
        monthborn = "April";
    } else if (month == 3) {
        monthborn = "March";
    } else if (month == 2) {
        monthborn = "Febuary";
    } else if (month == 1) {
        monthborn = "January";
    }
    return monthborn
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("You were born on " + monthborn + " " + day + " " + year);
}
```

I expected it to do print the year but it doesn't see the variable for some reason.

Comment: Variable exist in the scope/block where you declared them. In this case only inside the `monthConvert()` method and not inside the `main()` method.

Comment: You don't return a variable, you return a value.  In your case though, you do neither, since you never call `monthConvert()`.

Comment: Not to mention that `day` and `year` are never declared. Where do they come from?

Comment: and missing a `;` in return statement. You also refer to "the variable" lots of time, but at least once state **which** one is "the variable"!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're seeing is that `monthborn` is defined in one place – the `monthConvert()` method – and you're trying to use it in another placd - the `main()` method.

In your `main()` method, you aren't calling `monthConvert()` at all, so even though the method returns a value, you aren't calling the method.

You could do something like this to call the method and save the result in a variable:

```
String s = monthConvert(2);
```

Note that above is saving the value in a variable named `s` to highlight that the variable name inside `monthConvert()` has nothing to do with the variable name where you store the result.

Answer (score 0):

As people have commented the variable `monthborn` only exists in your `monthConvert()` method and not in the `main()` method. I have adapted your code and shown below to demonstrate how you call your method to get the `monthborn` variable.

Note: I removed the `day` and `year` variables as they have not been declared. yet

The line in question is:

```
String month = monthConvert(1);
```

It sets a new `month` variable equal to the string `"January"` as that is the string that is returned by your method when given the argument `1`

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String month = monthConvert(1);
    System.out.println("You were born on " + month);
}

public static String monthConvert(int month)
{
    String monthborn = "";
    if(month == 12) {
        monthborn = "December";
    } else if (month == 11){
        monthborn = "November";
    } else if (month == 10){
        monthborn = "October";
    }  else if (month == 9){
        monthborn = "September";
    } else if (month == 8){
        monthborn = "August";
    } else if (month == 7){
        monthborn = "July";
    } else if (month == 6){
        monthborn = "June";
    } else if (month == 5){
        monthborn = "May";
    } else if (month == 4){
        monthborn = "April";
    } else if (month == 3){
        monthborn = "March";
    } else if (month == 2){
        monthborn = "Febuary";
    } else if (month == 1){
        monthborn = "January";        
    }
    return monthborn;
}
```